# How to add CircularProgressIndicator in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have call three web services in one page now for that i want show only one CircularProgressIndicator.How to show CircularProgressIndicator first when i open screen after CircularProgressIndicator show all UI.

Comment: declare 3 bool variables then check them with bool1 && bool2 && bool3 in the condition ! Adding your code might help you better !

Comment: actually i used 3 Futurebuilder for 3 web services in future builder return sstatement is necessary  how to show one circularProgressIndicator for 3 methods

Comment: you need to show indicator until data arrive from service right ??

Comment: yes but when I'm open screen for example student attendance screen then it will show first circularProgress after data come in future builder then show all material design

Answer (score 2):

Use `Future.wait` to merge three futures (web service calls) then use `FutureBuilder` to show `CircularProgressIndicator` while waiting for the merged `Future` to complete.

Try it like this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _data1;
  String _data2;
  String _data3;

  Future<void> _webCall;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _webCall = _callWebServices();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> _callWebServices() async {
    await Future.wait([_webService1(), _webService2(), _webService3()]);
    return true;
  }

  Future<void> _webService1() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)); //TODO: do webservice call `get` or `post`
    _data1 = "This is data1"; //TODO: save the data
  }

  Future<void> _webService2() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)); //TODO: do webservice call `get` or `post`
    _data2 = "This is data2"; //TODO: save the data
  }

  Future<void> _webService3() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)); //TODO: do webservice call `get` or `post`
    _data3 = "This is data3"; //TODO: save the data
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _webCall,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot);
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return _buildProgressIndicator();
          else if (snapshot.hasError)
            return _buildError();
          else
            return _buildBody();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(_data1),
          Text(_data2),
          Text(_data3),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildError() {
    return Center(
      child: Text("Error while loading Web Services"),
    );
  }
}
```